# Inverse search in Kile (Ubuntu 13.10) doesn't work

Tags: 13.10, okular, kile

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, inverse search from Okular to Kile stopped working.

I did not change anything in my configuration of Kile or Okular:

In Kile:
Configure -> Tools -> Build ->Select a tool -> PDFLatTeX, Choose a configuration  for the tool PDFLaTeX-> Modern

In Okular: Settings -> Editor -> Kile, Command -> kile --line %l

Is this a bug, does it affect other users, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been reported here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/okular/+bug/1243692

and here

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326605

It seems that in order to make inverse search work, one should make sure that the "Browse" tool is selected in Okular, not "Zoom" or "Selection".

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. I run a 14.04 distro

Go to kile  toobar menu, choose *settings -> configure kile-> Build*  and then choose PDFLatex, as you did.

Check Modern configuration is selected. Go to the options text area and add `--synctex=1`. It should look like this.

```
-src-specials --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode '%source'
```

Now, <kbd>shift</kbd>+left click works, though you have to keep both pressed for a couple of seconds.

The information came from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/forward-search-in-emacs-for-okular-not-working